# JPA - Resolving relationships (ManyToMany + ManyToOne)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got some problem defining my relationships, currently I've got this entities:

[image: DataWarehouse]

I've tryed to make the relationships in code, like this:

**Project-DatosTabla**

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable(name = "datosTabla", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idProject", referencedColumnName = "idProject"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idTable", referencedColumnName = "idTable"))
public Set<DatosTabla> getDatosTabla() {
    return datosTabla;
}
```

**DatosTabla-Project**

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "datosTabla")
public Set<Project> getProject() {
    return project;
}
```

**DatosTabla-AtributosDatosTabla**

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "datosTabla")
public Set<AtributosDatosTabla> getAtributoDatosTabla() {
    return atributoDatosTabla;
}
```

**AtributosDatosTabla-DatosTabla**

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "idTable", referencedColumnName = "idTable"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "project") })
public DatosTabla getDatosTabla() {
    return datosTabla;
}
```

When I run the application, I got this error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK40oq9lkjvyu5b4s0x9j69uop4:AtributosDatosTabla [idTable])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (DatosTabla [idProject,idTable])

I've tryed to make composite key in **AtributosDatosTabla** by doing this:
**AtributosDatosTabla-DatosTabla**

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "idTable", referencedColumnName = "idTable"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "project") })
public DatosTabla getDatosTabla() {
    return datosTabla;
}
```

And I got this error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: project in DatosTabla

So, I'm quite stuck at this moment. Does anybody knows any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the `referencedColumnName` be *idProject* instead of *project* in your *AtributosDatosTabla*  entity definition (judging from your error message)? p.s on an other note why does your *DatosTabla* have a composite pk when your diagram (image) only shows a single pk

Comment: I've tryed to use idProject, but I got same error. I know that composite key must be an error, but I tryed a lot of things, and that one gived me different information, so i add that here.

Comment: Whats the error message you get when you used idProject as referenced column?